# Java, looping through result set

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

In Java, I have a query like this:

```
String querystring1= "SELECT rlink_id, COUNT(*)"
                   + "FROM dbo.Locate  "
                   + "GROUP BY rlink_id ";
```

The table rlink_id has this data:

```
Sid        lid
 3           2
 4           4
 7           3
 9           1
```

How do I extract these values with a Java ResultSet?

Here is what I have so far:

```
String show[] = {rs4.getString(1)};
String actuate[] = {rs4.getString(2)};
asString = Arrays.toString(actuate);
```

Answer (score 46):

```
List<String> sids = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lids = new ArrayList<String>();

String query = "SELECT rlink_id, COUNT(*)"
             + "FROM dbo.Locate  "
             + "GROUP BY rlink_id ";

Statement stmt = yourconnection.createStatement();
try {
    ResultSet rs4 = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs4.next()) {
        sids.add(rs4.getString(1));
        lids.add(rs4.getString(2));
    }
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}

String show[] = sids.toArray(sids.size());
String actuate[] = lids.toArray(lids.size());
```

Comment: shouldn't that be a "do- while"? Isnt the iterator already in the correct position for accessing first row at beginning? (else why should tutorials accessing first row only works otherwise)?

Comment: Definitely not (the query could return no row at all). What tutorial are you talking about?

Comment: ok thanks that fixed my problem.. U.U there was a wrong tutorial in first place in a google search, seems gone now.

Comment: doesn't this skip the first row? The position naturally starts at the first column. You need to execute rs4.beforeFirst(); before the while loop.

Comment: @GeorgeXavier nope!

Comment: On _.next()_ from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--): _"A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row"_.

Answer (score 18):

`Result Set` are actually contains multiple rows of data, and use a cursor to point out current position. So in your case, `rs4.getString(1)` only get you the data in first column of first row. In order to change to next row, you need to call `next()`

a quick example

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String sid = rs.getString(1);
    String lid = rs.getString(2);
    // Do whatever you want to do with these 2 values
}
```

there are many useful method in `ResultSet`, you should take a look :)

Comment: when i call this sid n lid somewhere through loop its giving me only first row of values

Comment: Doesn't the rs.next() in the while loop skip the first result?

Comment: @Durin : Check javadoc of [ResultSet.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) , the "cursor" is actually point **before** the first row when it is created :)

Comment: Don't forget a try finally to close your resultSet and your statement.

Answer (score 2):

- The ResultSet should be closed.
- PreparedStatement might protect agains SQL injection.
- **The PreparedStatement should be eventually closed.**

So the snippet might look like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()){
    while(rs.next()) {
        String val = rs.getString(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Modern Java

Other Answers here are good, but Java has evolved since they were posted. Let's address those improvements with some example code.

Your example code and data do not align. So I must invent another scenario.

| id_ | species_ | name_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat | Fluffy |
| 2 | dog | Rover |
| 3 | cat | Spot |
| 4 | cat | Tuna |

### Text blocks

Java now has [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378). This new syntax for string literals makes embedding SQL code easier. No more clumsy string concatenation.

Also you omitted the statement terminator in your SQL. I suggest always including the semicolon to avoid problems.

```java
String sql = """
        SELECT species_, COUNT(*)
        FROM animal_ 
        GROUP BY species_
        ;
        """ ;
```

### Try-with-resources

As others suggested, use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security attacks. Not relevant here, as you have no user input to protect against.

Nowadays `PreparedStatement`, and [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html), are [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close them after use. This simplifies your JDBC coding.

Ditto for `Connection` objects.

```java
try 
(
    Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery ( sql ) ;
)
{
    while ( resultSet.next() ) 
    {
        String species = resultSet.getString( 1 ) ;
        int count = resultSet.getInt( 2 ) ;
        System.out.println( species + " = " + count ) ;
    }
} 
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    …
}
```

> dog = 1
>
> cat = 3

### Records

You may want to define a class to hold the data returned by the result set.

If the intent of your custom class will be the transparent communication of immutable data, then define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

In a record, the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString` are created implicitly by the compiler.

Records are very convenient this kind of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) database work because a record can be defined locally within a method, as well as the usual ways of nested within a class or as a standalone class. (By the way, enums and interfaces can also now be local.)

```java
record SpeciesCount ( String species , int count ) {}
```

### Streams

Streams make easy work of looping through a collection. In our case, we can easily report our resulting collection of `SpeciesCount` objects.

```
results.stream().forEach( … ) ;
```

Or more simply:

```
results.forEach( … ) ;
```

We can use a method reference with our stream for compact syntax, such as `System.out :: println`.

```
results.forEach( System.out :: println ) ;
```

### `SequencedCollection`

We can sort the results with an `ORDER BY` added to our SQL query.

In Java 21+, a new super-interface above `List` and `NavigableSet`/`SortedSet` etc. has been added: [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html). See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

### Final example code

```java
String sql = """
        SELECT species_, COUNT(*)
        FROM animal_ 
        GROUP BY species_
        ORDER BY species_
        ;
        """ ;

record SpeciesCount ( String species , int count ) {}
SequencedCollection < SpeciesCount > results = new ArrayList<>() ;
try 
(
    Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery ( sql ) ;
)
{
    while ( resultSet.next() ) 
    {
        String species = resultSet.getString( 1 ) ;
        int count = resultSet.getInt( 2 ) ;
        SpeciesCount result = new SpeciesCount( species , count ) ;
        results.add( result ) ;
    }
} 
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    …
}

results.forEach( System.out :: println ) ;  // Dump results to console.
```

> SpeciesCount[species=cat, count=3]
>
> SpeciesCount[species=dog, count=1]

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your code is :

```
     String  show[]= {rs4.getString(1)};
     String actuate[]={rs4.getString(2)};
```

This will create a new array every time your loop (an not append as you might be assuming) and hence  in the end you will have only one element per array.

Here is one more way to solve this :

```
    StringBuilder sids = new StringBuilder ();
    StringBuilder lids = new StringBuilder ();

    while (rs4.next()) {
        sids.append(rs4.getString(1)).append(" ");
        lids.append(rs4.getString(2)).append(" ");
    }

    String show[] = sids.toString().split(" "); 
    String actuate[] = lids.toString().split(" ");
```

These arrays will have all the required element.

Comment: This is a strangest way of crating arrays I've ever seen. Moreover, what if one of strings you get contains a space?

Comment: OP is storing an int and not a string. So there wont be any space for sure. Its just another way to create an array apart from the ways suggested by other people.

Comment: Ok, this time it will work. For me it's like an anti-pattern. Programmers should unlearn bad patterns, and learn good patterns before it'll lead to critical system crash. I've seen this many times (unfortunately).

Comment: @peperg, the problem here was to create an array out of ResultSet and you would agree that there are multiple ways to accomplish it. I don't know what makes you see an anti-pattern in this.

Comment: This is a bit creative Santosh.