# Iterating over ResultSet and adding its value in an ArrayList

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, loops

I am iterating over an `ResultSet` and trying to copy its values in an `ArrayList`.
The problem is that its traversing only once. But using `resultset.getString("Col 1")` to `resultset.getString('Col n")` is showing all entries of all columns.
Below is the code snippet -

```
ResultSet resultset = null;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
int i = 1;
while (resultset.next()) {              
    arrayList.add(resultset.getString(i++));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 1"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 2"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col n"));
}
```

The only value of `ResultSet` getting copied into `ArrayList` is for column 1. And then while exits.
But I can see the value of all columns.
Why?

Comment: The value of variable i might become more then the columns

Comment: Should you add Java and JDBC to the tags?

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh No. it just ends in one iteration inside the while loop. the value of i on exiting is 2.

Comment: @JavaMan Yes, right. Added

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643576/java-looping-through-result-set

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, there are two possible problems here:

- `resultset` is `null` - I assume that this can't be the case as if it was you'd get an exception in your while loop and nothing would be output.
- The second problem is that `resultset.getString(i++)` will get columns 1,2,3 and so on from **each subsequent row**.

I think that the second point is probably your problem here.

Lets say you only had 1 row returned, as follows:

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col 3 
A    ,     B,     C
```

Your code as it stands would only get A - it wouldn't get the rest of the columns.

I suggest you change your code as follows:

```
ResultSet resultset = ...;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
while (resultset.next()) {                      
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= numberOfColumns) {
        arrayList.add(resultset.getString(i++));
    }
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 1"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 2"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 3"));                    
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col n"));
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the number of columns:

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultset.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
```

Comment: Yes.
resultset is NOT null.
the second point is the issue.
Question - Do I need to know numberOfColumns before hand? And does that mean hard-code it?

Comment: The code in the accepted answer won't get to the last column. ArrayLists index start at 0 but result sets start at 1. If metadata returns 11 for the number of columns, (i < numberOfColumns) will go from 1 to 10. It should be (i <= numberOfColumns) to get to the last column of the resultset.

Answer (score 12):

Just for the fun, I'm offering an alternative solution using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) and Java 8. Instead of using jOOQ, you could be using any other API that maps JDBC `ResultSet` to `List`, such as [Spring JDBC](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) or [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/), or write your own `ResultSetIterator`:

#### jOOQ 3.8 or less

```
List<Object> list =
DSL.using(connection)
   .fetch("SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...")
   .stream()
   .flatMap(r -> Arrays.stream(r.intoArray()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### jOOQ 3.9

```
List<Object> list =
DSL.using(connection)
   .fetch("SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...")
   .stream()
   .flatMap(Record::intoStream)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Comment: This looks really nice! convinced me to take a clooser look at JOOQ.

Comment: nice but unfortunately jooQ is rather pricey for commercial databases

Comment: @thg: You don't need jOOQ for such a simple query. You can easily use any of the other mentioned APIs like Spring JDBC, Apache DbUtils, or roll your own. The idea stays the same.