# How to store result set from sql statement in two different variable and use?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I want to store result set store two different location separately and use separately.Is that possible?

```
public void demo(){
    /* Result set got from the corpusSentenceRetrive method */
    ResultSet rsNew=corpusSentenceRetrive(wordAll);
    ArrayList<String> resultSetStore= new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    resultSetStore.add(i,rsNew);
    }

    method1(resultSetStore.get(0));
    method2(resultSetStore(1));
}

public void method1(ResultSet rst){
    ResultSet rs = rst;
    while (rs.next()) {....}
}

public void method2(ResultSet rst){
    ResultSet rs = rst;
    while (rs.next()) {....}
}
```

Why this is not work? How separately execute two method? Because of one method execute while statement .I couldn't use other method. That get 0 result set. How can I solve it easiest way?

Comment: What `MySQL` tag has to do with your question?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517736/iterating-over-resultset-and-adding-its-value-in-an-arraylist

Comment: @Anarki Actually I don't want to store result set values. I want to  add whole result set content in two location. Because I want to execute two method separately.

Comment: @Maduri you mean you want to pass same resultset in two methods?

Comment: @MiyaG Yes it is. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ResultSet contains an internal cursor of the location you are reading from. So when the first method is called and finished the cursor is at the end of the available results. So when the second method is called there are no results to check. Before using the results in either method you can call `ResultSet.beforeFirst()` to make sure the cursor is in the right place before using it.

Comment: Your the genius. You solved my big issue and valuable time. Thanx again and again. Have a nice day :) .

Answer (score 0):

As there is  no standard way to duplicate a `ResultSet` with db values, so you have to store data some where else. Most **ResultSet** implementations do not store all results in it but simply keep a connection to the database that is used to get the results as needed. So please use two different resultset or store all data of resultset to any other data structure e.g. List/Map etc. to perform above task as asked by you.

So you can't use same resultset twice.