# Selecting a certain row SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

So I have a data base (UserInfo) that has the attributes: Username, Email, Password etc. But I'm trying to SELECT all values from username, but separately so I can use them  individually as strings.
But I cannot find any syntax that allows you to pick from a certain row.

example:

```
SELECT Username FROM UserInfo WHERE **row number = 1**
```

so that it selects the username where the row number is 1 for example. any ideas?

Here is the code:
The last method allows me to check the number of fields under the attribute Username so then I can create the array size with that number x.

```
public void declaringDataBase() throws SQLException{

    conObj = DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/UserInfo","UserInfo","1234");
    statObj = conObj.createStatement();

    }
public void DisplayUsers() throws SQLException{



   String query = "SELECT Username FROM WHERE rownum = 2";  

   declaringDataBase();
   rsObj = statObj.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(rsObj.getString(1));

}

public void returnNumberInUsernameColumn() throws SQLException{

    String queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(Username) FROM UserInfo";


   declaringDataBase();
   rsObj = statObj.executeQuery(queryCount);

 String x = null;

 while(rsObj.next()){
     x = rsObj.getString(1); 

     }

   int returnValue = Integer.parseInt(x);
    System.out.println(returnValue);


}
}
```

The data base looks something like this:

```
Username(PK)     EmailAddress              Password
Joe01            joe@hotmail.co.uk         34590834ffjfdnkdfd
Frank22          Frank@gmail.com           ert543897ut034noegn
Ellie334         Ellie23@yahoo.co.uk       345903ejfbdvkdfvvdg
```

where the passwords are hashed.

I want to select say just Frank22 or Joe01 using some sort of integer so that I can increment it to get the other values at Username

Comment: "" where the row number is 1" makes no sense because you haven't got any numbers in your rows. What are you actually trying to achieve, and why? Surely as Username is the primary key, so it's unique, therefore it makes a lot of sense to select by that, as you'll always get exactly 1 or 0 rows. case it's just be `where Username = 'Joe01'` or whatever. Otherwise I'm not sure why you'd want to be selecting any old row or using a number for anything.  Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve, if not that?

Comment: No I will not know the Username name, I'm trying to fill an array(list) with the data from username and in order to do so, I have to fill each index with each username and I need to separate the usernames. Because using JDBC it only allows me to print the whole column Username as 1 string, so I need them separated.

Comment: "Because using JDBC it only allows me to print the whole column Username as 1 string"....er no, it should return you a result set. All DB interfaces will allow that, otherwise they'd be totally useless. I've no idea how you've managed to make it return a single string for the whole thing. `SELECT Username from UserInfo` should return you a resultset with a single column and you'll be able to loop through all the rows in the table. I'd have thought any JDBC tutorial would show you the basics. Perhaps show us your Java code then we can tell you how you've screwed it up and help you correct it.

Comment: I converted the result set to a string dude

Comment: Don't be rude, I'm clearly not an expert I'm an A-level student

Comment: "I converted the result set to a string"...why? Don't do that, keep it as a result set and you can use it as intended. Then you can get each individual pieces of data as a string and use it. P.S. Sorry I'm not trying to be rude, apologies if you thought that. You claimed it "only allowed to you use it as a string" which is not true at all, so I was merely pointing out that you must have misunderstood and/or messed up somewhere. Again if you'll show us the Java, we'll be happy to help you fix it, if you're unsure.

Comment: okay I will edit and post

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517736/iterating-over-resultset-and-adding-its-value-in-an-arraylist might help you see how to structure the code. Or this: http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-ResultSet-Loop.html (ignore the fact it's SQL Server data, the ResultSet idea should be the same). There are dozens of other examples online too if you search

Answer (score 1):

You can just select them all and then move the cursor.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Username FROM UserInfo");
rs.absolute(yourIndex);
String username = rs.getString(1);
```

To "get the other values at Username", you can iterate through the set.

```
rs.absolute(yourIndex);
System.out.printf("username at %d: %s%n", yourIndex, rs.getString(1));
while (rs.next()) {
    yourIndex++;
    System.out.printf("username at %d: %s%n", yourIndex, rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: I'' give this a go, seems like it's too complex though

Comment: @FranklinMemet Not sure what you mean, it's as easy as it gets.

Comment: This method should only be called on ResultSet objects that are scrollable (type TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    somefield
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5;
```

this example is giving you the 6th row, offset is telling it to skip first 5 rows
Works in PostgreSQL and mySQL

Comment: where "somefield" is Username?

Comment: you can ignore order by if you don't want to order
    example:
    SELECT Username FROM UserInfo LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2 ;
will give you Ellie334

Comment: @FranklinMemet did the answer help you??

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **offset** for that.

> Selects 1st `Username` of table `Table1`

```
SELECT Username FROM Table1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

> Note that offset value starts at 0 and limit means how many row(s) you want to select at once.

As my convenience you should use one more column `ID` for that                              `CREATE TABLE TABLE3(ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Name TEXT, Age INT);`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           And use                                                                                                                               `ALTER TABLE TABLE3 AUTO_INCREMENT=1`                                                                                                And after this access each row with id

Comment: it works on sqlite and sqlplus... Which one are you using?

Comment: Using JDBC I don't know what DBMS that is but MySQL is the syntax that generally works for it

Comment: As my convenience you should use one more column ID for that                              CREATE TABLE TABLE3(ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Name TEXT, Age INT);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't, add an ID attribute to your db table.

Then you can select any Username by his ID.

Example

```
SELECT Username FROM UserInfo WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: if I add an ID to my database it adds the issue of how will I allow those that sign in to automatically have the correct ID number assigned to their fields?

Comment: I guess you'll have to re-populate the database

Comment: @JérémySchaefer in OP's code Username is already the PK. Why do you want to add a separate key? Anyway if you read the latest comments on the main question you'll see that what OP is asking about is not actually the real problem at all.

Comment: @ADyson I see, yes... I though that the only problem was this PrimaryKey missing by the first edit of the post, my bad!

Answer (score -1):

Use the keyword `rownum`.

```
Select username from userinfo where rownum = 1
```

Comment: ROWNUM syntax doesn't exist in JDBC

Comment: not even in the query? the query isn't language independent?

Comment: Column 'ROWNUM' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'ROWNUM' is not a column in the target table.

Comment: There's no JDBC database it's the connectivity API, the database you're using is named Derby the equivalent of rownum for derby is ROW_NUMBER() function
here's the documentation:
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rreffuncrownumber.html