# make Java objects by parsing tabular data

Tags: java

i have data in tabular format as per following

```
id | Firstname | Lastname | Mo_Number 
--------------------------------------
1    Chirag      patel      77887*****
1    Chirag      patel      99002*****
1    Chirag      patel      88937*****
2    Devang      patel      90900*****
2    Devang      patel      45090*****
2    Devang      patel      65900*****
```

I want to parse this table in to java.

have made a following class in java class

```
package com.mirdb.model;

import java.util.Set;

public class Person {

private int id;
    private String fName;
private String lName;
private Set<String> moNumbers;


}
```

Can any one tell me the method which can give me the list of person objects by parsing above table.

Comment: tabular format is ok..but is it in database?

Comment: You should first search for `Java` `CSV` and come back with a concrete question.

Comment: yes .. the table is in the resultset object

Comment: what is primary key and combination I mean how you want to retrive data back..like one chirag patel having three mobile no?

Comment: Ya .. So I want to make one object with id 1 ...and it has mobile number attribute with Set datatype. So all mobile numbers with id 1 should be there in that object's set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming your data is in a database which you access via JDBC and you have a `ResultSet` that holds the data, you probably want to do something like this:

```
while(result.next()) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setId( result.getInt("id") );
    p.setfName( result.getString("Firstname ") );
    // ...
}
```

Obviously I am assuming your `Person` class has a visible default constructor and getter/setter methods for all fields. If this is pointing in the right direction, you should [look at this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html).

---

**Edit**: Adding info how you *could* (there are many ways!) handle multiple phone numbers per person.

```
Map<Integer,Person> persons = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();
while(result.next()) {
    int id = result.getInt("id");
    Person p = persons.get(id);
    if (null == p) {
        p = new Person();
        // .. add all info to person (without phone number)
        persons.put(id,p);
    }
    p.moNumbers.add(result.getString("Mo_Number"));
}
```

Comment: this is Fine but how can I get the mobile numbers Set so that I can set it to Person P

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is something which can do that out of the box, especially since you seem to be missing the ID parameter in your `Person` object.

A possible solution could be to have a constructor in your `Person` class which takes a string as a parameter. This string would represent a line in your text file which the constructor would then deconstruct (`.split("\\t")` maybe?) and then initialize the proper values according to the string which you have passed.

EDIT: Seeing your comment, you could try and do something as suggesting in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643576/looping-through-result-set-values) previous SO post:

```
List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<Person>();
while (rs4.next()) {
    pList.add(new Person(rs4.getString(0), rs4.getString(1)...);
}
...
return pList;
```

And for person:

```
package com.mirdb.model;

import java.util.Set;

public class Person {

private String ID;
private String fName;
private String lName;
private Set<String> moNumbers;

    public Person(String id, String fName, String lName, Set<String> moNumbers)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        ...
    }

    ...
    public String getID(){return this.ID;}
    ...

    public boolean equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;

        Person rhs = (Person) obj;
        return rhs.getID().equals(this.getID());
     }
}
```

EDIT: As per your other question: `But question is how can I make Set<String> moNumbers so that I can pass it to constructor??`

In your example you are only showing one masked number (at least that is what I think the `*` represent. If you have only one number, you could do this:

```
List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<Person>();
while (rs4.next()) {
    Set<String> mobileNumbers = new HashSet<String>();
    mobileNumbers.add(rs4.getString(3));
    // if on the other hand you have multiple comma delimeted numbers, you could try the approach below:
    //Set<String> mobileNumbers = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(rs4.getString(3).split(",")));
    pList.add(new Person(rs4.getString(0), rs4.getString(1), rs.getString(2), mobileNumbers);
}

return pList;
```

Comment: id is there in the person object. one more thing is two persons are equal if ids are same

Comment: Accessing database columns based on their order is a very bad idea!

Comment: i got your point. But question is how can I make Set<String> moNumbers so that I can pass it to constructor??