# Inserting rows into a ResultSet without update method in Java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, sqlexception

Q1: I have a loop inside which there is a select statement. Now I want to accumulate all these rows from select statement, into a ResultSet and then use it for other purpose outside the loop. How can I achieve that?

```
while(rs.next()){
  //some code..
  String sql2 = "select cast(multiset(select *  from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll("+ar.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")+"))) as UDT),"+rn+" as test from dual"; //returns a user defined datatype which is defined in my db schema
            PreparedStatement ps2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery(); //I need to use rs2 with all selected rows, outside the loop
            rs2.moveToInsertRow();
            rs2.updateObject(1, "update"); //why?
            rs2.insertRow(); 
   }
```

rs, here, is another `ResultSet`. UDT is user defined datatype in my db schema, and ar is an `ArrayList` defined and populated in //some code part.

Also, the raw select statement is something like:

```
select cast(multiset(select *  from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(1, 2, 33, 342))) as s9t_cells) from dual; //example
```

Q2: It didnt  make sense to me, why should I update the `ResultSet` object at all. I just want to get rows from the select statement and put them in the `ResultSet`. But it is stated in the process (as per https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_t0052611.html ) that I should add `UpdateXXX` method. If not added, I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Undefined column value on the insert row
```

Comment: q1) add them to an ArrayList that is defined before the loop

Comment: Please show us _all_ the actual SQL code you plan to run (having nothing to do with Java).  You can probably do this in one go with a single update/insert query.

Comment: *and then use it for other purpose outside the loop* - what this got to do with your code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Updated the code

Comment: Here are some related posts: [Looping thru resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643576/java-looping-through-resultset) and [Java tutorials - ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I mean, i need to use the resultset with populated rows and use it for another procedure call, outside the loop. For that I didnt write the code yet.

Comment: That doesn't help.  We need to see the _raw_ select query and then then raw update.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do u mean by raw ?

Comment: The opposite of cooked?  What I mean is, show us the select logic, as you would run it on the database, then show the update you want to do, or at least clearly express what that update logic is.

Comment: _I need to use rs2 with all selected rows, outside the loop_: Can't you add all the resultset rows into a `List` collection and use it outside the loop?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the question. Also, regarding the update, I dont want to update.  But everywhere it is written that I need to add that method call. (SQLException , if not added)

Comment: @prasad_ May be I can, but the type of List collection cant be specified. The select returns a UserDefined Datatype. (Question: If I create a List<Object> , will it work? I dont want to change the datatype though)

Comment: You can use result set's `getObject` and cast to the UDT type (it is generally a class, like `MyType`). That way you have a `List` of that class type. The code to cast: `MyType myType = (MyType) rs.getObject(1);`.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Also, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the UDT type values from a ResultSet (as a result of a
>   database query) and populate into a collection, and the data from the
>   collection is to be used in another procedure - outside the loop.

A user defined type is a Java class whose instances (objects) are stored in database table columns. UDTs are defined as table column data type and UDT instances are stored as column values. UDTs can be created and used in databases like Oracle, Apache Derby, etc.

A UDT is defined using the CREATE TYPE database command. A UDT value is stored in the database thru a Insert/Update DML and queried using a SQL Select. Like other database datatype's UDTs can be worked with using JDBC APIs or interactively using SQL.

Assuming the UDT type is of a Java class `MyType.java`, using JDBC, to insert/update a UDT value, the code can be like this:

```
    MyType myType = new MyType(); // an instance of the UDT type's Java class MyType
    preparedStatement.setObject(1, myType);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

To retrieve from the database and populate to a collection:

```
List<MyType> myTypesList = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    MyType myType = (MyType) rs.getObject(1);
    // ... other columns
    myTypesList.add(myType);
}
...

// Call a method that uses the myTypesList
processMyTypesFromDb(myTypesList);
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me in arriving to a solution for the issue :)

Comment: Also, can I ask one question, might be a bit off topic though.. can i use the datatype which is used in Oracle schema, in java, without creating it again ?

Comment: _can i use the datatype which is used in Oracle schema, in java, without creating it again_ For example? Like using it with another table's column type?

Comment: No, suppose I have created a table type in Oracle. Can i use it in java for converting an ArrayList to that table type?

Comment: _converting an ArrayList to that table type_: This statement is not clear.

Comment: I think, you can define a UDT with a Java class which has an `ArrayList` as an attribute. There are some rules like the Java class need to implement `java.io.Serializable` if it is to be used with a UDT - in case of Apache Derby. There may be some conditions like that in case using with Oracle (Oracle has good documentation - please lookup little bit). Also, it is possible that that the `ArrayList` element type may have to be serializable too. And, using an `ArrayList` as an UDT: you have to try and see.