# java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1 even though I counted the column

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am getting the error mentioned in the title from this code and Im not sure why...

```
public String[] getLobbies() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM lobby";
    SQLResponse<ResultSet> response = unclosedOperate(PreparedStatement::executeQuery, sql);
    SQLResponse<ResultSet> countResponse = unclosedOperate(PreparedStatement::executeQuery, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM lobby");
    if (!response.hasResponse() || !countResponse.hasResponse()) return new String[0];
    try {
        if (countResponse.getResponse().next()) {
            int count = countResponse.getResponse().getInt("count");
            String[] array = new String[count];

            if (response.getResponse().next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Logger.debug("count: " + count);
                    Logger.debug("i: " + i);
                    array[i] = response.getResponse().getString(i + 1);
                }
            }

            return array;
        }
        return new String[0];
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(response.getResponse());
        close(countResponse.getResponse());
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

It's printing this to console...

```
[07:14:57 ERROR]: count: 2
[07:14:57 ERROR]: i: 0
[07:14:57 ERROR]: count: 2
[07:14:57 ERROR]: i: 1
[07:14:57 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.
```

This shouldn't be happening..?
SQL is one indexed is it not? There are two entries in the column, I want to retrieve both of those entries, but when I retrieve the second entry it throws that error, even though when I count the entries it shows there being 2 in there...
Oh, and my table currently looks like this...
https://gyazo.com/8af53da8b78b38a63864ae5a1a8f43e6

Comment: If you only have a single column in your table, you cannot select `getstring(2)` -- hence the out of range exception...  You need to call `response.getResponse().next()` multiple times instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is you aren't iterating through the result list, but instead trying to access the next column in the resultset from the response.  Since you're resultset only returns a single column, you can only access `getString(1)` (columns are offset by 1 instead of starting at 0).

Instead of calling `getResponse` and then looping, loop and call `getResponse` for each row, always calling `getString(1)` (or being a little more explicit and using the actual column name).

```
    if (countResponse.getResponse().next()) {
        int count = countResponse.getResponse().getInt("count");
        String[] array = new String[count];
        Logger.debug("count: " + count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (response.getResponse().next()) {
                Logger.debug("i: " + i);
                array[i] = response.getResponse().getString(1);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

With that said, this could be greatly simplified.  You don't need to get the `count` to instantiate the array.  And then you could just use `while` to loop through the responses and build your array...

Comment: @Realmm I'm not familiar with the wrapper you are using for `prepared statements`.  But take a look here for a much simpler way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7643634/1073631

Comment: It's actually a mini lib I made for myself to handle SQL easier...
Check it out if you want:
https://github.com/Realmm/RealmCommons/tree/master/main/java/me/realm/commons/database/sql
(The class that this method is called in is extending MySQL)