# Gson: class com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection declares multiple JSON fields named connectionLifecycleInterceptors

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, gson, resultset

I am trying to query a database and then convert the resultset obtained into json using the google gson library.While trying todo so, i am getting the error:
class com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection declares multiple JSON fields named connectionLifecycleInterceptors

I have tried to look for the connectionLifecycleInterceptors variable to change the name however i cant.Other questions in this context are not refering only to superclasses and subclass,while the error i am getting,i suppose comes from the database resultset.

```
 public String convertToGson(ResultSet results)  throws Exception 
  { //code to convert resultset to gson
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String gsonstring = gson.toJson(results);///it indicates the error is here
    return gsonstring;
   }
```

here is the error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection declares multiple JSON fields named connectionLifecycleInterceptors
at
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
at sample.QueryCentre.convertToGson(QueryCentre.java:91)
at sample.QueryCentre.showavailablerooms(QueryCentre.java:72)
at sample.ServerSide.main(ServerSide.java:51)

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` is not a regular `POJO` and you need to iterate over it and manually create `POJO` or `Map` instance. After this conversion you can pass list of these instances to serialisation process.

Pseudocode:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
while (results.next()) {
    Map<String, Object> mapForRow = createMapFrom(result);
    rows.add(mapForRow);
}
String json = gson.toJson(rows);
```

Helpfull methods:

- [getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData())
- [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

See also:

- [Java, looping through result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643576/java-looping-through-result-set/7643634)
- [ResultSet to List](https://gist.github.com/cworks/4175942)